# Derivation of moment generating function for limiting distribution of sum of logbeta distributed variables

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, moment-generating-function, characteristic-function, gumbel-distribution

A sum of logbeta distributed variables occurs in this question [Distribution with a given moment generating function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143027/distribution-with-a-given-moment-generating-function)

Let, $X_j \sim Beta(j\sigma, 1-\sigma)$, $Y_j = -\log(X_j)$ and $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j - \frac{1-\sigma}{\sigma}\log(n)$ then the moment generating function of $S_n$ approaches, for $n \to \infty$

$$E(e^{tS_n}) \to \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\sigma^t\Gamma(1-t)}$$

How is this derived?

Comment: While going through some of my old questions, and trying to close whatever is reasonably answered, I encountered this problem. I had been able to come up with a solution, but, I find some steps not very intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

The expectation of $E(e^{tS_n})$ is similar to $E(Z_{n,t})$ where $Z_{n,t}$ is a product

$$Z_{n,t} = e^{tS_n} = e^{-t\sum_{j=1}^n \log X_j -t \frac{1-\sigma}{\sigma} \log(n)}= \left( n^{(1-\sigma)/\sigma} \prod_{j=1}^n X_j \right)^{-t}$$

And the expectation of a product of independent variables is the product of the expectation of the individual variables

$$E(Z_{n,t}) = n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma}  \prod_{j=1}^n E( X_j^{-t}) $$

The expectation $E(X_j^{-t})$ for a beta distribution is

$$E(X_j^{-t}) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)} \int_0^1 x^{-t} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} dx = \frac{B(\alpha-t,\beta)}{B(\alpha,\beta)}$$

We get to

$$E(e^{tS_n}) = n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma} \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{B(j\sigma-t,1-\sigma)}{B(j\sigma,1-\sigma)} $$

We can rewrite the beta function in terms of gamma functions $B(x,y) = \Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)/\Gamma(x+y)$

$$\begin{array}{}
E(e^{tS_n}) & = & n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma} \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{\Gamma(j\sigma-t)}{\Gamma(j\sigma-t+1-\sigma)} \frac{\Gamma(j\sigma+1-\sigma)}{\Gamma(j\sigma)} \\ &=& n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma} \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{\Gamma(j\sigma-t+1)}{\Gamma((j-1)\sigma-t+1)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma((j-1)\sigma+1)}{\Gamma(j\sigma+1)} \cdot  \frac{j\sigma}{j\sigma-t}
\end{array}$$

in the second line we rewrote the gamma function such that we get terms $\Gamma((j-1)\sigma+1)$ and $\Gamma(j\sigma+1)$ where the difference is only in $j$ versus $j-1$. This makes that many terms cancel because in the sum they appear both once in the numerator and once in the denominator.

$$\begin{array}{}
E(e^{tS_n}) &=& n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma}   \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-t)}  \cdot \frac{\Gamma(n\sigma + 1 -t)}{\Gamma(n\sigma +1)} \cdot  \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{j\sigma}{j\sigma-t} \\
\end{array}$$

using $\Gamma(1+z) = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+1/j)^z}{1+z/j}$

$$\begin{array}{}
E(e^{tS_n})  &=& n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma}   \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-t)}  \cdot  \frac{\Gamma(n\sigma + 1 -t)}{\Gamma(n\sigma +1)} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{1}{1-\frac{t/\sigma}{j}} \\
 &=& n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma}   \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\Gamma(1-t)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(n\sigma + 1 -t)}{\Gamma(n\sigma +1)} \cdot  \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{1}{1-\frac{t/\sigma}{j}} \prod_{j=1}^\infty  \frac{1-\frac{t/\sigma}{j}}{(1+1/j)^{-t/\sigma}} \\
 &=& n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma}   \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\Gamma(1-t)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(n\sigma + 1 -t)}{\Gamma(n\sigma +1)} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{1}{(1+1/j)^{-t/\sigma}} \prod_{j=n+1}^\infty  \frac{1-\frac{t/\sigma}{j}}{(1+1/j)^{-t/\sigma}} \\
 &=& n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma}   \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\Gamma(1-t)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(n\sigma + 1 -t)}{\Gamma(n\sigma +1)} \cdot (1+n)^{t/\sigma} \cdot \prod_{j=n+1}^\infty  \frac{1-\frac{t/\sigma}{j}}{(1+1/j)^{-t/\sigma}}\\
&\approx& n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma}   \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\Gamma(1-t)} \cdot (n\sigma + 1)^{-t} \cdot (1+n)^{t/\sigma} \cdot \prod_{j=n+1}^\infty  \frac{1-\frac{t/\sigma}{j}}{(1+1/j)^{-t/\sigma}}
\end{array}$$

in the limit for $n \to \infty$

$$\begin{array}{}
\lim_{n \to \infty} E(e^{tS_n})  &=&n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma} \cdot (1+n)^{t/\sigma} \cdot (n\sigma + 1)^{-t} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\Gamma(1-t)} \\
&=& \underbrace {\left( \frac{(1+1/n)^{1/\sigma} }{\sigma + 1/n}\right)^t }_{\to 1/\sigma^t} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\Gamma(1-t)} \\ &=& \frac{\Gamma(1-t/\sigma)}{\sigma^t\Gamma(1-t)}
\end{array}$$

Comment: If you still need steps to get $1/\sigma^t$, then writing $\frac{n \left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)^{1/\sigma }}{n \sigma +1}$ as $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)^{1/\sigma }}{\frac{1}{n}+\sigma }$ and applying  L'Hôpital's rule once will get a form that you can just plug in $\infty$ for $n$ to get the limit.

Comment: @JimB I got the last step. Or at least, I did it intuitively (not with L'Hopital's rule). The term $(1+1/n)^{1/\sigma}$ approaches $(1)^{1/\sigma}=1$ leaving $n/(n \sigma + 1) \approx n/(n \sigma) = 1/\sigma$. But indeed, it could be done more formally.

Comment: I find the derivation still simple untill $$E(e^{tS_n}) = n^{-t(1-\sigma)/\sigma} \prod_{j=1}^n  \frac{B(j\sigma-t,1-\sigma)}{B(j\sigma,1-\sigma)}$$ but after that I am applying some standard rules to get to the end result, but it is not intuitive anymore.

Comment: Where you have "nominator" do you mean to say "numerator"? (I do this myself.)

Comment: As just commented here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143027/distribution-with-a-given-moment-generating-function?noredirect=1#comment1007733_143027 I suggest working wi the log MGF to help with limits.

Comment: @julyan I've posted a partial answer to the original question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143027/distribution-with-a-given-moment-generating-function/548831#548831.